# TG API авторизация пользователей и получение данных

Tags: php, telegram, madelineproto

Создала приложение Telegram Apps. Получила api и hash.

Не понимаю как с tg api реализовать возможность авторизации пользователей, чтобы получать данные о каналах, которыми пользователь владеет.

Язык PHP. MadelineProto даже не запускается. Библиотека выдаёт ошибку `Fatal error: Uncaught \danog\MadelineProto\Exception: stat():` и много других. Возможно есть по данной библиотеке грамотная инструкция или готовый пример для тестов?

Апи вк в этом плане гораздо проще был

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пара недель изучения библиотеки и всё вышло. Но шифрование конечно портит всю малину и многие функцию зависают или работают неполноценно

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/823885)